# C Free array pointer for stack

Tags: c

I'm trying to free an array used to create a stack; however, I keep getting an invalid pointer error. I have an array of longs to represent the stack and an additional element at array[-1] to represent the amount of stacks I have. STACK_NUM = 1

```
int numElements; 

void delete_Stack (long ** spp) {
    int index;
    for(index = -1; index < numElements; ++index){
        free((void *) spp[index]);
    }
    free(spp);
    spp = NULL;
}

long * new_Stack (unsigned long size) {
    void * memory = malloc((size + STACK_NUM) * sizeof(long));
    long * this_stack = (long *) memory + STACK_NUM;
    return this_stack;
}

int main(int argc, char * const * argv){
   long * stack;
   stack = new_Stack(5);
   numElements = 5;
   delete_Stack(&stack);
}
```

Comment: Your code as a major fault anyway: `numElements` is always undefined. You probably wanted: `numElements = array[-1];` I don't know if that works though.

Comment: its because i used array[-1] for the amount of stacks i created

Comment: @00_td_00 and now your code isn't going to compile...

Comment: sorry numElements was defined as a global var but i forgot to add it

Comment: @00_td_00 Please add it outside the function bodies.

Comment: And you have 0 array elements, making the index -1 valid? That makes no sense obviously. Perhaps you are passing `&array[1]` around to functions as the stack pointer, so the first stack is `spp[0]` (`array[1]`) and `spp[-1]` (`array[0]`) is the number of stacks?

Comment: Yeah please show us your function calls — a lot of information is missing in your question.

Comment: These allocation and deletion functions don't go together at all. Show how they are actually used.

Comment: Could we write the new_Stack function like this? 

`long * new_Stack (unsigned long size) {

    long * this_stack = (long *) ((size + STACK_NUM) * sizeof(long));

    return this_stack;
}`

Why we need a void pointer if I may ask?

*PS* : I don't know how to put the codes in new lines :(

Comment: Can you explain how your program is supposed to work, step by step?

Comment: The logic for `delete_Stack()`, even ignoring the index issues, is for an array of stacks. The logic for `new_Stack()` and the rest of your program is for a single stack. You need to fix `delete_Stack()` to only `free(*spp); *spp = NULL;` or change the rest of your program to use an array of stacks. It looks as if you tried to debug the problem you had in your deletion function (or expand your program to work with multiple stacks) and forgot to change the rest of your logic to match your intent.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: one `malloc()`ation matches one and only one `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `stack = new_Stack(5);` you are calling malloc once. and storing the result in `stack`.

When you call `delete_Stack(&stack);` you are calling free 5 times on `stack[i]` and then another free on `stack`.

This is not required. For this `new_stack` you just need to call free once. This function will work properly with the given `new_stack`

```
void delete_Stack (long ** spp) {
  free((*spp)-STACK_NUM);
  *spp = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it calls `free` 5 times on `(&stack)[i]`, then `&stack`. Which is just wrong since `stack` is a local variable.

Comment: The allocated pointer is returned one element further, so freeing it will cause issues. That's why -1 "works" also.

Comment: "*... and storing the result in stack.*" Err, what please?

Comment: This answer, does not fully refer to the actual issue, so it's proposal is misleading. Please be more clear which parts refer to the OP's question's issue and which parts are proposals on how to approach this entirly different.

Comment: @alk stack here refers to the variable in the program, therefore it is marked as code. As for your second comment, the code written by OP does not match. The allocation function does not match the free function. I proposed a solution by changing the free function. There can be another solution by changing the allocation function, but the way to go was less clear in that case, so I did not propose that solution.

Comment: Ahok, sure. Sry missed this.

Comment: But your changes to the function freeing the memory would not work with the OP's code.

Comment: To work with the OP's `new_Stack()` function the `free(*spp);` in your snippets should be `free((*spp) - STACK_NUM);`.

Comment: Also this statement "*Any element at array[-1] will be an part of the previous variable in the stack.*" I also misunderstand or it's just plain wrong. Please not that `free((*spp) - STACK_NUM)` is the same as `free(&(*spp)[ - STACK_NUM])`.

Comment: You are right, again. :) I will remove that part of the answer.